# Load Wordpress template based on page you are leaving

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to load the same post in Wordpress with a different page template based upon what URL a user has left to view the post.

So, if I have a post called "Post 1", and I click on it from a path such as www.mysite.com/flowers, then the post is loaded using the 'single-flowers.php' template. However, if the same post is selected from the page www.mysite.com/basketball, then the same page content is loaded, but with the page template 'single-basketball.php'. On the back end of Wordpress, the author can select the categories 'basketball' and 'flowers' to ensure the post displays in the correct places on the website.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to grab the prev url

```
$ref = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
$regex = '/mysite.com\/flowers\//';
if (!empty($ref) && preg_match($regex, $ref)) {
  get_template_part('single', 'flowers');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vitali - where would you run that code - in functions.php or elsewhere?

Comment: In single.php i guess, in case it is a default post_type, and create an else condition